# Non-synchronous buck ASIC's diode selection makes sense?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck, synchronous

While selecting buck converter ASIC for a design I came across various synchronous and non-synchronous buck converter from different manufacturers. *Synchronous buck are OK - no problem with SW node due to lower FET*, **however**, while going through the datasheets of non-synchronous converters and **trying to select the Schottky diode, the SW pin limits seems problematic**
[LM5012](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5012.pdf)

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you select a Schottky diode, while free-wheeling, the voltage drop across it would be more than 0.3V and SW node will see a more negative voltage than -0.3V, which does not guarantee reliable operation.

If you breach absolute maximum IC will definitely fail. And if you are operating b/w Recommended operating condition and Absolute maximum, it becomes a slow burn scenario.
Even this E2E [forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/1249711/lm5012-lm5012-maximum-on-time-and-sw-pin-voltage-rating/4736743#4736743) replies are not satisfactory.

Basically for an application of 1A or 2A, if you go and select a Schottky diode MPN, you need to select huge diodes with huge packages like D2PAK

E.g ([STPS5045S](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stps5045s.pdf) suggested in comments), if we want to stay within 0.3V drop @2A application, **we need to stay in the yellow region and may have to use 2 diodes in parallel (assuming a curve b/w Tj = 125degC and Tj = 25degC)**
[image]

Comment: So what is the problem or question really? Select a diode that is rated/guaranteed for voltage being less than 0.3V over it under free-wheeling conditions, or, believe the FAE who says during switching it's OK for a brief time to exceed 0.3V as long as it's not constant DC or otherwise past 1.5V which the chip can't handle? Why is that not satisfactory?

Comment: @Justme it's not that simple. When designing a reliable system, you need to consider these things. Please check Forward voltage vs Instantaneous Forward current graph in the datasheet of any Schottky diode.  Across various ambient temperature condition, you will be b/w Recommended and Maximum Ratings.

Comment: I understand, but if a FAE from chip vendor says it's OK, why isn't it OK to you? If you have no countering evidence by testing and validating the chip performance and degradation for hours under varying temperature conditions - which the chip manufacturer has validated already for you - then you have no evidence it's not OK.

Comment: @Justme I'll always follow the datasheet only. In the last comment you can see, he's also not sure and suggesting to use a synchronous buck instead.

Comment: I get it that chip manufacturer has validated that. That's how the datasheet has been made and I don't want to play outside Recommended operating conditions.

Comment: Simple: "Recommended" is not a rating.

Comment: @TimWilliams please check the 3rd highlighted image

Comment: Maybe it's mentioning about applying -0.3V or lower continuously, although it doesn't make sense for a switching regulator IC. Also, from the block diagram or in general, I can't see why/how having -0.3V or lower voltage on SW pin can cause a problem inside the IC. All I can see is that the internal MOSFET's body diode can turn on during freewheeling when VIN is zero, which is practically unlikely (unless you short the input whilst the switch is off). If you worry about the voltage drop then there are numerous low-Vf schottky diodes available such as STPS5045S and SDT30B100.

Comment: The only problem I see is that the SW pin is the reference to the high side FET Gate Driver. More than -0.3V can cause it to fail at some time.

And yeah the diode you suggested is good however if you check Figure 7 of STPS5045S the voltage drop starts at 0.3V (25degC) and after junction temperature is increased (125degC) then only it stays well below 0.3V for let say 2A application.

I think diodes like these can be tested to see the forward voltage drop and also can be connected in parallel to further divide the forward current and reduce voltage drop.

Comment: @Justme completely understand that "Select a diode that is guaranteed to have <0.3V voltage drop" however while looking for diodes myself and the diode that RohatKilic has suggested 'STPS5045S' is 90A rated D2PAK package (huge in size) and we may have to parallel them to achieve <0.3V drop for an application of 1-2 A load current. 
That's why my question is "Do these non-sync buck make sense" because to stay within Recommended condition, huge diodes need to be used in parallel. Hope you understand the concern.

Comment: @divyam You won't have to parallel them, but they're grossly oversized for your purposes.

Comment: Have a look at [LM5013 EVM](https://www.ti.com/tool/LM5013-Q1EVM) (LM5013 has similar ratings), and check the freewheeling [diode](https://www.vishay.com/docs/89170/v8p12.pdf) used in that 12V/3.5A regulator design. The forward drop is higher than 0.3V for 1A. Apparently, even TI themselves don't care about the SW node voltage, or in other words they don't take the recommended conditions as an absolute reference.

Comment: Yeah that's why I posted the question, and if they don't take it seriously and put Disclaimer Notes, like the one in 3rd highlighted image, then it is definitely a weird product. Maybe all manufacturers have an IC like that, so why not make one of you own.
I'll probably use an IC like UCC27282 (HS recommended till -8V) with external mosfets and control the PWM. But they are not making these kind of ASIC. Maybe it's a business decision. Don't really know :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For non-synchronous buck ASICs, to operate within recommended operating conditions, an overly sized diode is required.**

However, if the manufacturer is **OK** with operating b/w Recommended and Absolute ratings then Notes like below should not be there in the first place.
[image]